# How can we convert Dialogflow agent Json file to Lex bot Json file?

Tags: node.js, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, dialogflow-es, watson-virtual-agent

I have exported Json file from my Dialogflow Agent and trying to import it in Lex Bot. Wondering if any setting is available in Lex bot to import Dialogflow Agent and convert it to native Json format.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a difference between Alexa & lex JSON format, if yes, you will have to do it manually. Dialogflow allows you to export agent according to Alexa JSON format. Please check snap below:

[image]